# Create views whose columns are the result of a query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I've limited knowledge of Oracle and its PSQL language. I am trying to create two views which gave me simpler access to the data I need for an application I am working on.

Given a table:

[image]

I would like to create the sold and bought views. Any suggestions?

Comment: how many company names can the table have?

Comment: roughly 2 thousands

Comment: Then you should PIVOT, but do you understand that it would mean 2000 columns?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala this is not a duplication as I am not able to use an aggregation operator in the table